# How do you create a GitHub Repository so that I can automatically import and export python scripts?

Tags: python, github, repository

I'm brand new to Github but experienced using Python and just wondered how to use both so that I can upload and export scripts for others to use! I have created a repository to start with! Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

for a beginner with GitHub as you, it will be great to use GitHub desktop.
Download it and clone the repository you created. Now move your files into the repository folder. In GitHub desktop add a quick summary about what you changed and click the "commit" button. With this you created a timestamp in the history of your repository, but it is only available on your local machine. Now click the "push origin" button on the top in GitHub desktop. This will push the changes to the repository. When your repository will become more popular, people might want to commit changes to it. To do this, they will open a pull request and you just need to approve it and their changes will be merged into your repository. I hope this helped. If you don't understand anything about GitHub, feel free to ask. :)